# Animating opacity with Raphael

Tags: javascript, svg, hover, raphael, opacity

I've successfully made a small map that reveals .SVGs upon mouse hover. It instantly reveals the image, then leaves on mouse out. I have tried adding the '.animate' attribute to make them fade in and out, but every way I have tried has failed? Would love a quick explanation!

var rsr = Raphael('map', '900', '900');

var regions = [];

var circle_a =
rsr.circle(584, 556, 88); circle_a.attr({fill: '#2a4b4d',opacity: '0'}).data({'id': 'circle_a', 'region': 'Circle A'});
regions.push(circle_a);

for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {

```
regions[i].mouseover(function(e){
  this.node.style.opacity = 1;
});

regions[i].mouseout(function(e){
    this.node.style.opacity = 0;
});
```

}

Comment: What .animate attribute is that? Can you create a [mcve] with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
regions[i].mouseover(function(e){
  circle_a.animate({ "fill-opacity": "1" }, 2000);
    document.getElementById('region-name').innerHTML = this.data('region');
});

regions[i].mouseout(function(e){
circle_a.animate({ "fill-opacity": "0" }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I was trying 'opacity' over and over. But then I set the fill opacity on my svg to 0 (instead of opacity). Then animated the fill opacity. Everything works! Woooo.